# `suffix-out` in Racket

Tags: module, racket

I can use [`prefix-out`](http://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/require.html?q=prefix-out#%28form._%28%28lib._racket%2Fprivate%2Fbase..rkt%29._prefix-out%29%29) to rename my exported identifiers to have all have a similar prefix. For example:

```
#lang racket
(provide (prefix-out mymod: (all-defined-out)))
(define x 5)
(define y 6)
```

And now `mymod:x` and `mymod:y` should be bound to `x` and `y` inside of that file.

Is there a similar way to add a suffix to all of the identifiers a module is exporting? So that I can do something like:

```
#lang racket
(provide (suffix-out -from-mymod (all-defined-out)))
(define x 5)
(define y 6)
```

And now any module that required this one would have `x-from-mymod` and `y-from-mymod` bound to `x` and `y` in this module.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [`filtered-out`](http://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/require.html#%28form._%28%28lib._racket%2Fprovide..rkt%29._filtered-out%29%29) for this purpose:

```lisp
(require (for-syntax racket/base
                     racket/provide-transform
                     syntax/parse)
         racket/provide)

(define-syntax suffix-out
  (make-provide-transformer
   (lambda (stx modes)
     (syntax-parse stx
       [(_ suffix:id provide-spec)
        (expand-export
         #'(filtered-out (lambda (name)
                           (string-append name (symbol->string 'suffix)))
                         provide-spec)
         modes)]))))
```

Comment: Thank you. One thing that I have actually always been curious about, do you know what the difference between `filtered-out` and `rename-out` is?

Comment: @LeifAndersen `filtered-out` is effectively `filter-map` over a list of exports, but `rename-out` is just an explicit renaming list. That is, the former can operate over an arbitrary set of exports, but `rename-out` lists them one by one. The two that are more closely related are `rename-out` and `only-out`; the former exports everything and renames the listed identifiers, but `only-out` only exports the identifiers you explicitly list.